# Core data filtering

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a core data structure as follows:

`Business <-------->> Employee <-------->> Address`

Each business has multiple employees and each employee can have multiple addresses.

From the Business object, I want to be able to get an `NSArray` or `NSSet` of all the `Address` objects that specify a certain condition. E.g. All the street names have to be unique.

I know that I could override the `isEqual:` but I'm guessing this is going to have unintended results. Otherwise, I have been looking into using `valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects"`, but I don't think I can pass a condition.

Here is some code that I have so far:

```
    NSMutableArray *addressArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *employees = [Employee sortedArray];

    //loop through employees
    for (Employee *employee in employees) {
        for (Address *address in employee.addresses) {
            [addressArray addObject:address];
        }
    }

    //filter out duplicates
    addressArray = [addressArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.city"];
```

This code gives me a list of unique cities, however, I want a collection containing `Address` objects that have unique `city` values (or some other condition).

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no unique solution. If there is more than one address with the same city, which address object should be chosen? Your solution below chooses "the first one", which is random, because the the object in the array do not have a well-defined order.

Comment: That's true. I was using that as a bit of a simplified example. I have a custom property that is generated based on a couple other properties. In my case the first one is fine, but I was using it as a simplified example of filtering unique objects based on a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with the [LinqToObjectiveC library](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#distinct):

```
NSArray* addressesWithUniqueCities = [input distinct:^id(id address) {
    return [address city];
}];
```

Looking at the source, the underlying implementation is as follows:

```
typedef id (^Selector)(id item);

-(NSArray *)distinct:(Selector)keySelector
{
    NSMutableSet* keyValues = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* distinctSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id item in self) {
        id keyForItem = keySelector(item);
        if (![keyValues containsObject:keyForItem]) {
            [distinctSet addObject:item];
            [keyValues addObject:keyForItem];
        }
    }
    return distinctSet;
 }
```

My final code ended up being:

```
    NSMutableArray *addressArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *employees = [Employee sortedEmployees];

    //loop through employees
    for (Employee *employee in employees) {
        for (Address *address in employee.addresses) {
            [addressArray addObject:address];
        }
    }

    //filter out duplicates
    NSArray *distinctAddressArray = [addressArray distinct:^id(id address) {
        return [address addressLine];
    }];

    return distinctAddressArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you meant but you could try something like: (untested)

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) addressesForBusiness:(Business*)business
                         sectionProperty:(NSString*)sectionProperty
{

    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Address"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employee.business == %@",business.objectID];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:sectionProperty ascending:YES]];

    NSArray* addresses = [business.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray* sections = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray* currentSection = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSManagedObject* prevAddress = nil;
    for (NSManagedObject* address in addresses) {
        if (prevAddress && ([[address valueForKey:sectionProperty] isEqual:[prevAddress valueForKey:sectionProperty]])) {
            currentSection = [NSMutableArray new];
            [sections addObject:currentSection];
        }
        prevAddress = address;
        [currentSection addObject:address];
    }

    return sections;
}
```

This will return an array of arrays where each internal array hold objects with the same property value. In your example you could call:

```
[[self class] addressesForBusiness:someBusiness sectionProperty:addressLine];
```